# C# Run MySQL Update Query as Localhost user

Tags: c#, mysql, webforms

I'm working on a .NET WebForms C# website and I normally use SQL Server but I have a project which is requiring use of a MySQL database, and I'm able to resolve most problems but not this last one: I can't run **updates** on a database or I get an error. The error I'm getting is this:

> UPDATE command denied to user 'xxxx'@T'mymachine' for table 'pages'

The advice I was given to overcome this is as follows:

> You need to express the login as xxxx@localhost and run it on the database server (MySQL users are bound to localhost on that server)

Slight issue is... I can't find any advice on how to express a login as a localhost user, or how to run a query as a localhost user. It defaults to xxxx@mymachine, rather than xxxx@localhost, which is why it doesn't work. Could anyone help me with how to run a query as a localhost user?

For my queries I'm connecting using the following:

> Server=00.00.00.00;Database=(databasename);Uid=xxxx;Pwd=(password);

My query is a rather simple one:

```
MySqlConnection connection = null;

try
{
    var query =
        string.Format(
            "UPDATE pages SET approvedDate = {1} WHERE id = {0};",
            pageId, approvedDate);

    connection = new MySqlConnection(Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

    var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.Text
    };

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    (exceptionstuff)
}
finally
{
    connection?.Close();
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Edit:
To stop you needing to read the comments for this, the first thing I tried was changing the username to xxxx@localhost, like this:

> Server=00.00.00.00;Database=(databasename);Uid=xxxx@localhost;Pwd=(password);

and I got this error instead:

> Access denied for user xxxx@localhost@mymachine

Comment: reread what it told you bout logging in as localhost .. it shows you exactly how to reference it login@localhost - just change the userID in front of the @

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, and then it denied me access on user xxxx@localhost@mymachine.

Comment: Dont use 2 @ symbols its just Pete@localhost

Comment: Did you check the user have enough privileges to update. Go to user accounts check the privileges, if you are using wamp.

Comment: I'm assured the "xxxx" account I'm using has full editor permissions, and I can delete information just fine but can't update. It could be permissions based. I'm having someone else investigate that now.

Comment: I'm told the "xxxx" user has full access to all the tables, so it "can't" be a permissions problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you tried `Server=localhost;Database=(databasename);Uid=xxxx;Pwd=(password);`?

Comment: If I put "Server=localhost" will that not try looking for the database on my machine (e.g. that I'm hosting it), rather than connecting to the remote IP which I blanked out with all 0s above? I'm not hosting the database on my own machine, I'm connecting to it and the only way the update works (apparently) is if it's a localhost user running it. 

I'm starting to think I need to get the client to reconsider how they want this to work.